# How to unit test an array of dates?

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, unit-testing, date

I am working on learning how to unit test, complete newb here. I built this function that returns a Date array given an initial date passed as a string.

I see the skeleton code that it is generated. I understand what it is doing, but I cannot conceive of a way to code it such that the expected value is an array containing *any* number of *whatever* dates.

Any tips?

Function I wrote:

```
Public Function getHolidayList(ByVal startingDate As String) As Date()
    Const DATE_FORMAT As String = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    Dim ERROR_DATE() As Date = {Date.Parse("06/06/6666")}
    Dim commandText As String
    Dim command As OracleCommand
    Dim dataSet As New DataSet
    Dim connection As OracleConnection

    If startingDate <> Nothing AndAlso startingDate <> "" AndAlso Not startingDate.Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
        startingDate = startingDate.Trim
        Try
            Date.Parse(startingDate)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ERROR_DATE
        End Try
    Else
        Return ERROR_DATE
    End If

    If ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SYSTEM") = "TEST" Then
        connection = New OracleConnection(ConnectionStrings("HRTEST").ConnectionString)
    Else
        connection = New OracleConnection(ConnectionStrings("HRIS").ConnectionString)
    End If

    commandText = "select holiday.h_date from holiday_t1 holiday where holiday.h_date between " & _
      "to_date('" & startingDate & "', " & DATE_FORMAT & "') and " & _
      "to_date('" & Date.Now.ToShortDateString & ", " & DATE_FORMAT & "')"

    command = New OracleCommand(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("HR_SCHEMA"), connection)
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    command.CommandText = commandText

    connection.Open()
    Dim dataAdapter As New OracleDataAdapter(command)

    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)
    connection.Close()
    connection.Dispose()

    Dim holidays(dataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1) As Date
    For i As Integer = 0 To dataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        holidays(i) = dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0)
    Next

    Return holidays
End Function
```

Skeleton unit testing code automagically-generated:

```
<TestMethod(), _
 HostType("ASP.NET"), _
 AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\Users\url\here", "/projectRootDirectory"), _
 UrlToTest("http://localhost/projectRootDirectory")> _
Public Sub getHolidayListTest()
    Dim target As fmlaDB_Accessor = New fmlaDB_Accessor ' TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    Dim startingDate As String = String.Empty ' TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    Dim expected() As DateTime = Nothing ' TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    Dim actual() As DateTime
    actual = target.getHolidayList(startingDate)
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)
    Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For it to be a true Unit Test, you would need to isolate it from the database. You can isolate it from the database by moving the db call to another class that you could mock. That would allow you to have more control over what is returned, as tests that relay on certain values being in the DB are very brittle and will degrade over time, and give false negatives if the test runner is unable to talk to the database.

As it stands you could right an integration test for it. As to what to assert, you could lean on the compiler to give you the expected value.

```
<TestMethod> _
Public Sub Test()
    Dim [date] = DateTime.Now
    Dim result = getHolidayList([date])
    Assert.AreEqual(Nothing, result)
End Sub
```

Then once you have the value from the failing test, plug it in to the `Assert`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the tip! Just a quick clarification question:
Once a test method is created and works properly, does it automatically generate random values when it is executing (in my case, random strings to use for a starting date) in a fuzzing-like way, or am I supposed to code generator fuctions? 

If the latter is true, how would they be used or called in a test function?

Comment: @roggmatz not unless you tell it to. Usually you would give in a specific value and expect a corresponding result. In your edit, where you have the 'TODOs for starting and expected is where I would expect your starting value and corresponding result to be set.

Comment: How would you tell Visual Studio to fuzz a function?

Comment: Either via a mocking framework like I aluded to in my first paragraph (im not sure what vb has tbh) but that normally requires code to be constructed using a DI approach or something like [Microsoft Fakes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh549176.aspx)

Comment: If this has answered your question don't forget to upvote and [mark it as the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). I'm going to bed now, if you have any other questions you can always [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) another :)

Comment: I would not recommend to fuzz or randomize any data in a Unit Test. One Unit Test should test exactly one fix aspect of your interface. I encourage to read also Rober C. Martin´s [Blog](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/12/17/TheCyclesOfTDD.html) about TDD.